# Matlab iterating through files in a folder, and check if the file name has specific characters

Tags: matlab, loops, filenames, netcdf

I have some climate data files (netcdf) of the same dimension.

For example:
agg_humidity_bc_historical_1980_2001.nc

agg_humidity_bc_future_2020_2040.nc

agg_wind_bc_historical_1980_2001.nc

agg_precipitation_bc_future_2020_2040.nc

.....

I have a program in MATLAB to extract a specific data point from every single file. I want to iterate through all the files, check the variable name in the file name, e.g. humidity, wind, precipitation etc., and extract the data based on the variable. Then I want to store these extracted values to csv files with the same name of the nc files, like:

agg_humidity_bc_future_2020_2040.csv

agg_wind_bc_historical_1980_2001.csv

agg_precipitation_bc_future_2020_2040.csv

Here is the code I have by now.

```
mkdir test
data=dir('*.nc');

  for i=1:length(data)
  ncFile=data(i).name

  ??? How to check which variable is in the ncFile? 

  %%Got the index of the location of
  LonInd=22;
  LatInd=10;

  if variable=humidity
    SH=ncread(ncFile,'humidity',[LonInd, LatInd, 1], [1 1 inf]);
    SH=squeeze(SH);
    fid = fopen(['test\' ncFile.csv],'w'); 
    fprintf(fid,%d,SH)
  else if variable=wind
    wind=ncread(ncFile,'wind',[LonInd, LatInd, 1], [1 1 inf]);
    wind=squeeze(wind);
    fid = fopen(['test\' ncFile.csv],'w'); 
    fprintf(fid,%d,wind)
    fid = fclose(fid);
    fid = fclose(fid);
  else if variable=wind
    precipitation=ncread(ncFile,'precipitation',[LonInd, LatInd, 1], [1 1 inf]);
    precipitation=squeeze(precipitation);
    fid = fopen(['test\' ncFile.csv],'w'); 
    fprintf(fid,%d,precipitation)
    fid = fclose(fid);
end
```

Can anybody help me finish this code?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html

Answer (score 2):

With what I understand, ncFile contains the list of file and you want to distinguish certain file according to the file name?

If that is what you want to do them, you can do:

```
ncFile = data(1).name 
result = findStr(ncFile, 'desired file name')
```

Then check if the result is empty or not (you can use `isempty`). If the result is empty, the ncFile is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Sushant. This is exactly what I want. I will try to finish the code, and see if it works well.